# I need a working example to retrieve a public youtube playlist using youtube Data API 3 for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube, playlist

Am looking for a good example on how to use google's youtube Data API 3 for retrieving a public playlist items using JavaScript, I seem to be struggling to find one in google's own website, the Playlist examples seem to be missing something, they just don't work, I think that google should pay more attention to the documentation of their API.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on which "Playlist examples" you were looking at and what you mean by "they just don't work"?

Comment: neelsg thank you for paying attention, the problem with the examples is that they were scattered into pieces and not clear how to make a working playlist retrieval...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var playlistId = "your_playlist_id",
        APIKey = "your_api_key",
        baseURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/";

    $.get(baseURL + "playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=" + playlistId + "&key=" + APIKey, function(data) {
        // Do what you want with the data
    });

});
```

Comment: Very short and beautiful answer thank you very much Damien! :) and I will post my own answer with full steps for others to know more about the whole process, thank you again! :)

Comment: Dear Damien I can't make your jquery code to work it displays the following error: GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults…mGQMDG1VzugzVdpGLdJcg9L3-oMei0&key=XXXX 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: OK it worked after removing the Referrers, I was accessing the api using local host and local host cannot be a Referrer. Thank you again Damien.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working! According to google's documentation we do the following steps:

1- Create a "project" in Google's Developers Console.
2- Enable "youtube data API 3" in Google's Developer's Console.
3- Create an "API Key" in Google's Developers Console(I have included two hosts 'my own local host' and 'http://www.myownwebsite.com/').
4- Get your public youtube playlist ID (http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXXXXXXXXXX the id is the alphanumeric string after PL).
4- Then we add the following in the HTML page:

```
<head>
<script>
        function load() {
            var playListID = "YOUR_PUBLIC_YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_ID";
            var requestOptions = {
                playlistId: playListID,
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: 10
            };
            var apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            gapi.client.load('youtube','v3', function () {  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(requestOptions);
                                                            request.execute(function (data) { console.log (data) });
                                                        });

        }
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=load"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```